# Re-organising the data with desired sequence

Tags: fortran, sequence, reorganize

I revise my posted question.
Here is my Fortran code.

```
line  1   PROGRAM COMPA
line  2   IMPLICIT NONE
line  3   
line  4   INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
line  5   INTEGER            :: i, j, k, l
line  6   REAL (KIND=dp)     :: ap(116,6), lr(3,3), pl(3), ns(2,116)
line  7   
line  8   OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='data.dat', STATUS='OLD')
line  9   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
line 10   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
line 11   DO i = 1, 3, 1
line 12      READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) pl
line 13      lr(i,:) = pl
line 14   END DO
line 15   READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*)
line 16   DO i = 1, 116, 1
line 17      READ (UNIT=3, FMT=*) pl
line 18      ap(i,4:6) = pl
line 19      ns(:,i) = i
line 20   END DO
line 21   
line 22   DO i = 1, 116, 1
line 23      ap(i,1) = ap(i,4)*lr(1,1)+ap(i,5)*lr(2,1)+ap(i,6)*lr(3,1)
line 24      ap(i,2) = ap(i,4)*lr(1,2)+ap(i,5)*lr(2,2)+ap(i,6)*lr(3,2)
line 25      ap(i,3) = ap(i,4)*lr(1,3)+ap(i,5)*lr(2,3)+ap(i,6)*lr(3,3)
line 26   END DO
line 27   
line 28   DO i = 2, 116, 1
line 29      l = i
line 30      DO j = 1, i-1, 1
line 31         IF ((ap(l,1) < ap(j,1)) .OR. &
line 32            ((ap(l,1) == ap(j,1)) .AND. (ap(l,2) < ap(j,2))) .OR. &
line 33            ((ap(l,1) < ap(j,1)) .AND. (ap(l,2) == ap(j,2)) .AND. &
line 34            (ap(l,3) < ap(j,3)))) THEN
line 35            k = ns(1,i)
line 36            ns(1,j+1:i) = ns(1,j:i-1)
line 37            ns(1,j) = k
line 38            l = j
line 39         END IF
line 40      END DO
line 41   END DO
line 42   
line 43   OPEN (UNIT=4, FILE='compare.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
line 44   DO i = 1, 116, 1
line 45      DO j = 1, 116, 1
line 46         IF (ns(1,j) == i) WRITE (UNIT=4, FMT=*) ns(:,j), ap(j,1:3)
line 47      END DO
line 48   END DO
line 49   
line 50   CLOSE (UNIT=3)
line 51   CLOSE (UNIT=4)
line 52   STOP
line 53   END PROGRAM COMPA
```

My code reads the following data.dat file content. and ap(i,4:6) stores the original data from the file; while, ap(i,1:3) stores the data after processing ap(i,4:6).

I want to re-organise the line number for each row, based on the ascending sequence for the 1st value in each row. If the 1st value is same in two or more rows; then, take the 2nd value for the ascending re-organising sequence. If the 2nd value is same in two or more rows; then, take the 3rd value for the ascending re-organising sequence.

Here is the data.dat file.

```
         116
 Parameter
   0.2951429939E+02    0.0000000000E+00    0.0000000000E+00
   0.0000000000E+00    0.1500000000E+02    0.0000000000E+00
   0.0000000000E+00   0.0000000000E+00   0.2510000038E+02
 Parameter
   0.000000000    0.500000000    0.300000012 
   0.041669998    0.500000000    0.328289986 
   0.041669998    0.500000000    0.384860009 
   0.000000000    0.500000000    0.413150012 
   0.000000000    0.500000000    0.469720006 
   0.041669998    0.500000000    0.498010010 
   0.041669998    0.500000000    0.554579973 
   0.000000000    0.500000000    0.582870007 
   0.083329998    0.500000000    0.300000012 
   0.125000000    0.500000000    0.328289986 
   0.125000000    0.500000000    0.384860009 
   0.083329998    0.500000000    0.413150012 
   0.083329998    0.500000000    0.469720006
...
```

Here is the compare.dat file, which was written by the code for the re-organised data.

```
   1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        7.5000000000000000        7.5300004152000044     
   2.0000000000000000        7.0000000000000000        1.2298607965527013        7.5000000000000000        13.919957533040389     
   3.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        7.5000000000000000        14.630037397190604     
   4.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000        1.2298607965527013        7.5000000000000000        12.500051440243805     
   5.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        7.5000000000000000        11.789972329093603     
   6.0000000000000000        13.000000000000000        2.4594265091401013        7.5000000000000000        11.789972329093603     
   7.0000000000000000        16.000000000000000        2.4594265091401013        7.5000000000000000        14.630037397190604     
   8.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        7.5000000000000000        10.370065458197006     
   9.0000000000000000        21.000000000000000        4.9191481317598029        7.5000000000000000        11.789972329093603     
   10.000000000000000        102.00000000000000        15.042847316209118        7.5000000000000000        14.464879495090205     
   11.000000000000000        114.00000000000000        13.527288986990197        7.5000000000000000        13.589893105343398     
   12.000000000000000        91.000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        7.5000000000000000        6.4399073735966041     
   13.000000000000000        69.000000000000000        23.365586106424487        7.5000000000000000        9.6599863721468040     
   14.000000000000000        83.000000000000000        27.054873530174486        7.5000000000000000        7.5300004152000044     
   15.000000000000000        84.000000000000000        28.284437826075518        7.5000000000000000        8.2400787733501950     
   16.000000000000000        24.000000000000000        4.9191481317598029        7.5000000000000000        14.630037397190604     
   17.000000000000000        104.00000000000000        17.216575554825518        7.5000000000000000        15.719879815290209     
   18.000000000000000        89.000000000000000        28.284437826075518        7.5000000000000000        13.919957533040389     
   19.000000000000000        64.000000000000000        20.905862978575517        7.5000000000000000        12.500051440243805     
   20.000000000000000        36.000000000000000        9.8380015632401978        7.5000000000000000        10.370065458197006     
   21.000000000000000        80.000000000000000        25.825011966250003        7.5000000000000000        12.500051440243805
```

Obviously, this re-organisation is wrong because the row was not written based on the ascending order.

Would anyone please give me some suggestions on what is wrong with my code? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do, but your code obviously doesn't switch entire rows, but only some pieces of rows, and it even scrambles the rows.

Comment: @Kieren, please revisit your question and explain more carefully what you are trying to do. Why does your code apparently swap columns 4:6 in one element with columns 1:3 in another element and what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: @PierU I am sorry for that I did not write my question clearly. I re-wrote my question. Would you please have a look at it again and give me suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @lastchance I am sorry for that I did not write my posted question clearly. I re-wrote my question and explain what ap(i,1:3) and ap(i,4:6) store. Would you please have a look at it again and give me some suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I'm still mystified. Have you got a link to the original problem? What are you actually trying to do? (What are the contents of ap(,) supposed to represent?) This is turning into an XY problem.

Comment: @lastchance This is my own data and there is no link to the problem. The variable 'ap(i,4:6)' stores the original data from the data.dat file, starting from the 7th line; while, 'ap(i,1:3)' stores the converted data from ap(i,4:6). I want to re-organise the converted data, ap(i,1:3), through the ascending order. Would you please give me some suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the rows according to the 1st column, then 2nd column, then 3rd column?

Comment: @PierU Yes, this is exactly what I want to do with my code but the re-organising sequence is obviously not correct. Would you please give me some suggestions on the solution? Thank you.

Comment: Please be more concrete. Which sorting algorithm did you implement? I am not against implementing one's own sorting as an exercise, but be also aware that there are libraries available. Also, what is the meaning of the columns in the output file?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава sometimes re-implementing a sorting algorithm can be easier than using a library if the latter doesn't exactly fit the needs. That said there are two issues in this code: 1) I can't see either which sorting algorithm the OP is trying to implement (maybe bubble sort, but I'm not sure), and 2) the OP uses an array of indexes to avoid explicitely moving the data, but they doesn't use the indexes to access the data.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for the suggestion. I modified my code in the posted question with line number. I am using bubble sorting method to re-organise my data but something is wrong with my code. The 1st columns in the output file is the row index after the re-organisation and the 2nd column is the row index before the re-organisation. The 3rd ~ 5th columns are the converted data by line 22 ~ line 26 in my code. Obviously, my code did not organise anything and I do not know why is that. Would you please give me some suggestions on what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for code clarity let's define a utility function tells if a row is "smaller" or not compared to another row (because it uses assumed shape arguments, this function must be in a module, or in the `contain` section of the main program):

```
logical function is_smaller(rowa,rowb) result(s)
real(dp), intent(in) :: rowa(:), rowb(:)
s = .false.
if (rowa(1) < rowb(1)) then
    s = .true.
else if (rowa(1) == rowb(1)) then 
    if (rowa(2) < rowb(2)) then
        s = .true.
    else if (rowa(2) == rowb(2)) then 
        if (rowa(3) < rowb(3)) s= .true.
    end if
end if
end function
```

Then let's use it with an insertion sort algorithm, which is is fine for such a number of elements to sort. For code clarity again we move the data instead of using indexes (indexes would be more efficient).

```
   real(dp) :: tmp(6)
   ...
   do i = 2, 116 
       ! the first (i-1) rows are sorted, we are now looking at row i
      do j = 1, i-1
         if (is_smaller(ap(i,:),ap(j,:))) then
            ! insertion of row i at position j
            tmp(:) = ap(i,:)
            ap(j+1:i,:) = ap(j:i-1,:)
            ap(j,:) = tmp(:)
            exit
         end if
      end do
   end do
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I modified my posted question again, using the insertion method to re-organise the row index; however, the result is still not correct. This code just has the same structure as my original code and, due to the special requirement in my original code, I can only re-organise the row index; not the row. Would you please have a look at my posted question again and give me more suggestions? Thank you again.

Comment: I don't think your new code be a correct implementation of insertion sort. Moreover you have obsviously skipped one my comment below your question : "the OP uses an array of indexes to avoid explicitely moving the data, but they doesn't use the indexes to access the data"

Comment: Between Line 44 and Line 48 in my code, I use the re-organised row index to access the data and output the row data in the new re-organised sequence. Would you please have a look at my code and gvie me more suggestions? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: My suggestion at that point is that you carefulling read the comments. When I say "to access the data" it includes during the double sorting loop itself. All your comparisons use the loop index i/j/l and not at the sorting index ns(). Besides, there is something that had already been told you in previous questions: do NOT continuously overwrite your question, add updates instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think that I know the problem in my code now. By the way, is there any link explaining how to update posted code in the comment zone? I do not know how to update the new code so I overwrite my question. Thank you again.

Comment: When you edit your question, just add the new code instead of replacing the original one. Of course if it's just minor changes (typos etc) you can modify the original one.